# create new dataframe column as needed for each new item in list

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm scrapping some information from several profiles in linked in through selenium.

I have a list of links to scrap the data in a for loop and get the information of that current profile and save it on a list. After saving that information I put it in a list.

I want to create a new column for each link visited (ie. every person gets a new column.

What I tried was:

```
profile_dct = pd.DataFrame()

profile_dct = [name_list, location_list, flat_job, flat_ed]
```

However, this just adds the information in the same column.

I assume this is because I did not specify to add the list values to a specific column. However, I do not have a predetermined set or named column for this data frame and I want to create a new column as needed for every item in the for link in list_list

What I want would look something like

```
    column1                   columnn2               column3
    name                       name2                 name3
    location                  location               location
    company1,company2         company1               company1, company2, company3
    date1,dat2                date1                  date1, date2, date3           
   job_loc1, jobloc2          job_loc1               job_loc1, job_loc2, job_loc3
   desc1, desc2               desc1                  desc1, desc2, desc3
   college1                   college1, college2     college1, college2, college3
   degree1                    degree1,degree2        degree1, degree2, degree3
```

Where the job and ed list contains company, date, job location and description.

```
for job in jobs:
    exp['job'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class$="t-bold"] span').text]
    exp['company'] += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal\']:nth-child(2) span")?.innerText',
                              job)]
    exp['date'] += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal t-black--light\']:nth-child(3) span")?.innerText',
        job)]
    exp['job_location'] += [driver.execute_script(
        'return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal t-black--light\']:nth-child(4) span")?.innerText',
        job)]
    exp['description'] += [
        driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("ul li ul span[aria-hidden=true]")?.innerText',
                              job)]

job_list.append(list(exp.values()))
```

The education list contains college and degree

```
ed = {key: [] for key in ['College', 'Degree']}
        edu = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#education)>div>ul>li')

for education in edu:
                driver.implicitly_wait(30)
                ed['College'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold\'] span').text]
                ed['Degree'] += [driver.execute_script(
                    'return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal\']:nth-child(2) span")?.innerText',
                    education)]
                #ed['Degree'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'t-14 t-normal\'] span').text]
    
education_list.append(list(ed.values()))
    
flat_ed = [item for sublist in education_list for item in sublist]
```

How can I create a new column every time it loops through the for loop without pre-creating columns for the dataframe?

I looked through existing answers but they have existing columns they want to add to as opposed to creating a new column as needed.

UPDATED THE QUESTION FOR CLARITY

Comment: Add an example of what one column looks like, eg, `col1 = ['John S', 'United States', ..., ['College 1', 'college 2', ...], ...]`. From my current understanding, you want certain rows to have array/list as the members

Answer (score 1):

Every column needs a column name as well, so assuming `name`, `name2`, etc is unique, you can:

```py
link_fields = ['name', 'location', 'job', 'ed']  # fields to fetch for each profile
profile_dct = pd.DataFrame([], index=link_fields)
for link in list_list:
    person_data = get_data(link)
    assert all([key in link_fields for key in person_data.keys()])
    profile_dct.loc[:, person_data['name']] = person_data
```